# Send BUSD instead of BNB

Tags: web3js, tokens, nodejs, ethers.js, react

Hey guys so I'm looking to build a donation button of sorts that requires a set amount of BUSD to a smart contract address I've already deployed! My only issue is that I can't seem to find a way to send BUSD instead of BNB which is set automatically as the accepted token! how would you go about this? I want to send 0.40 BUSD instead of 0.40 BNB and I want to lock the button so that it only accepts BUSD as payment!

```
const contractHandler = async({setTxn}) => {
try {
  const {wallet} = window;
  
  if (wallet) {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(wallet);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    
    console.log("Initialize Payment");
    const txn = await signer.sendTransaction({to: contractAddress, value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.40")});
    setTxn([txn])
  } else {
    console.log("Ethereum object does not exist");
  }
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

}

Comment: before looking at that does øu contract support transferring BUSD?

Comment: I've tested it with BNB and it worked well! I've also tested it with sending custom tokens as well (not from react). I haven't been able to check if it accepts BUSD just yet

Comment: any address can take the tokens. the problem is can your contract transfer them out to you later :D ?

Comment: your contract need explicitly a function to transfer the token by its owner to another address otherwise the token will stuck there. but that is not your question

Comment: Yes I know that, I've actually added a function which, given the address of a token will withdraw the funds back to the owner (me). I'm also using testnets right now so my funds are not in danger whatsoever I am mostly running tests :)

Comment: what you are currently do is sending `{to: contractAddress, value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.40")}` a normal transaction to your contract with some value of the native token. if you want to send an erc20 then you need to send a tx to contract address that manage that token and give the amount and address of your contract as data. similar to this Adding transfer functionality  in https://blog.logrocket.com/building-dapp-ethers-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
const signer = <the signer>;
const addressOfYourContract = '0x...';
const amountInTheSmallestUnit = BigNumber.from("10000...");
const busdContractAddress = '0x...';
const busdContractAbi = `....`;
const busdContract = new ethers.Contract(busdContractAddress, busdContractAbi, signer);
const tx = await busdContract.transfer(addressOfYourContract, amountInTheSmallestUnit);
const txResponse = tx.wait();
```

You can get the busdContractAbi from etherscan

3 things to take care of:

- your contract support and can transfer the tokens if it has them (this should be implemented in the smart contract code)
- the given amount in should be the smallest unit. If the token has decimal 18 then to send 1 token you need BigNumber.from("1000000000000000000"); and use BigNumbers because js cannot handle those big numbers
- Test that code it is only an example :) no warranty

Comment: I seem to be getting the grasp of it and I'm getting closer. right now this one has a bit of a problem as this line -> const busdContract = new ethers.Contract(busdContractAddress, busdContractAbi, signer); 
has a typerror of abi is undefined for some reason. I've found the abi and copy pasted it in a json file so the variable itself doesn't seem to be an issue so I'm a bit confused xD

Comment: can u try to past it directly in code using ‘ …. ‘ and not json file ?

Comment: I will try to check that tomorrow

Comment: I DID IT!!! turns out my ABI variable really was undefined so I fixed it by adding the abi directly like you suggested! thank you so much!!

Comment: welcome , accept it as answer if it helped you